# Getting 403 error when trying to push library to maven repository

Tags: java, maven, kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I want to publish my kotlin library to maven repository but i always get this error

```
Execution failed for task ':publishMavenPublicationToTestRepository'.
> Failed to publish publication 'maven' to repository 'test'
   > Could not PUT 'https://mymavenrepo.com/repo/oeXkQu5cUtNHmcWwJd1R/com/test/public/commons/1.0.0/commons-1.0.0.jar'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
```

This is my gradle file

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.20"
    `maven-publish`
    `java-library`
    signing
}

group = "com.test.public"
version = "1.0.0"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // My dependencies
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict", "-Xopt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn")
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("maven") {
            groupId = "com.test.public"
            artifactId = "commons"
            version = "1.0.0"
            from(components["java"])
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            name = "test"
            url = uri("https://mymavenrepo.com/repo/oeXkQu5cUtNHmcWwJd1R/")
            credentials { 
                username = "xxx"
                password = "xxx"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This error happens when i try to publish to maven repository, but when i try to publish it to maven local everything works.

What is the problem with my configuration and how to solve it?

Comment: Did it work before or is this a completely new try? Which repo manager runs at `mymavenrepo.com`? Did you check user `xxx`'s credentials/permissions there? It's no wonder that it works with your local repo (default `~/.m2/repository`). Usually there's just local file access involved: no network, no server, no extra login/no extra access permissions (but those from the local OS).

Comment: 403 means "forbidden".  You don't have the required permissions to publish to the maven repository.  Check that you are using the correct credentials and / or talk to the people who manage the repository.

Comment: what Gerold is getting at I think is that it might be that you (or someone else) already published this version to the repository and its set to disallow overriding it. 403 could be the result of you trying to do exactly that

Comment: Hi user13548798, were you able to solve your problem? I am facing the same issue.